# input text reloads with interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I am having trouble with a div that I reload every 15 seconds with PHP and ajax. It is working fine but the only thing I would like to know is if it is possible to load an input text and when the interval refresh the div not to refresh the input text as sometimes when you are writing in the input it just reloads and you have to write again.

here is some part of the code: 
File 1 where I load the content into a div by ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('#precio').load('valoractual.php');
}, 15000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
});
// ]]></script>
```

Here is the form that reloads:

```
 <p>Current Bid:  <?php echo "USD ".$puja; ?></p>
                                              <p><form id="bid" name="bid"> 
                                              <input type="text" name="puja" placeholder="<?php $sobrepujar = $puja + 500; echo $sobrepujar; ?>" id="puja" size="14" /><input type="hidden" id="usuario" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['idusuario']; ?>" /><input type="hidden" id="valoractual" value="<?php echo $puja; ?>" /><input type="hidden" id="idpuja" value="<?php echo $idpuja; ?>" /> <input type="button" id="submit" value="B I D"/>
              </form>
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Re)load the page only if the #puja element is not available on the page or (it has no focus and and empty value):

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug.  without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {

if($("#puja").length == 0 || (!$("#puja").is(":focus") && $("#puja").val() == "")) {

    $('#precio').load('valoractual.php');
}

}, 15000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div.  it is in milliseconds. 
});
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: It doesn´t load the file as #puja is in the file to be loaded and the script is on the main one